# Express App on Docker with Typescript not working

Tags: docker, express, dockerfile

I'm trying to run my api in a docker container but when I send requests its failing with this error on Postman:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000

When the container is running I do not get any errors, I see logs that my MongoDB is connected and I have a log that the API is running on host:port

My Setup as folllows:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:13-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

**Package.json:**

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "nodemon --config nodemon.json src/app.ts",
"build": "tsc -p .",
"start": "ts-node dist/app.js"
},
```

My API works fine if im running locally (outside a container) but just cant get it to work with docker. Even if i run command **yarn build** and **yarn start** it works fine as expected.

Comment: expose is not doing much besides of providing some information of the user of your image. It doesnt not publish the ports, you cannot control this from a dockerfile. So the question is, how do you run the container? Do you publish the ports ? `docker run --publish 3000:3000 myapp` ?

Comment: I run container with this docker run -p 3000:3000 myApp